# Opencv python: apply arbitrary function to each pixel without iterating

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Is there a way in opencv with python to apply an arbitrary function to each pixel in an image while taking advantage of numpy's optimizations?

For example, I'd like to get the sigmoid of a single-channel image:

```
out_image[:,:] = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-in_img[:,:]))
```

But this does not work (not surprisingly): `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`.

Is there a way to coax numpy into doing something like this?

I could of course iterate over the pixels, and that would likely be fine in C++, but in python it's very slow.

Comment: Try replacing `math.exp` with `np.exp`.

Comment: That works as the solution to this specific problem. Could I also define an arbitrary function that operates on a single pixel, and coax numpy into running it quickly? Or would any function I write need to operate directly on numpy arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Divakar, replacing `math.exp` that only knows about scalars by `numpy.exp` that also knows about `ndarray` is the way to go.

As a side note, some benchmarks:

```
in_img = numpy.random.random((1000, 1000))
```

In CPython:

```
%timeit (1 / (1 + numpy.exp(-in_img[:,:])))
```

10 loops, best of 3: 51.1 ms per loop

With numexpr:

```
import numexpr
%timeit numexpr.evaluate("1 / (1 + exp(-in_img))")
10 loops, best of 3: 27.9 ms per loop
```

With Numba (assuming you annotated your function correctly as in the following)

```
import numpy
from numba import vectorize, float64
@vectorize([float64(float64)])
def f(x):
    return 1 / (1 + numpy.exp(-x))
```

You get:

```
%timeit f(in_img)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.34 ms per loop
```

With pythran (assuming you compiled the following function)

```
#pythran export f(float[][])
def f(in_img):
    return 1 / (1 + numpy.exp(-in_img[:,:]))
```

Compile it with:

```
pythran f.py -DUSE_BOOST_SIMD -march=native
```

And bench it:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 5.07 ms per loop
```

Comment: That works as the solution to this specific problem. Could I also define an arbitrary function that operates on a single pixel, and coax numpy into running it quickly? Or would any function I write need to operate directly on numpy arrays?